# mostrar 3 decimales

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

Estoy usando el framework CI3,
donde mi DB tienes la columna costos maneja decimales(8,2)
estoy implementando el siguiente código desde
desde mi archivo.js

```
$('input[name=precioProducto]').val(round(selectedItemValue.venta,2));
```

Me nuestra el numero con 2 decimales (1.00), yo quiero trabajar con 3 decimales es decir con (1.000)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Depende de lo que necesites. Puedes usar toFixed(3) o puedes crear una función personalizada dependiendo de cómo quieras manejar el redondeo.

Comment: Estimado, agradezco tu respuesta, e implantado el codigo de la siguiente forma pero nome muestra nada.
$('input[name=precioProducto]').val(toFixed(selectedItemValue.venta,3));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione, implementando el siguiente código, gracias por su respuesta

```
$('input[name=precioProducto]').val(parseFloat(selectedItemValue.venta).toFixed(3));
```